# Google Measurement Protocol: update revenue

Tags: transactions, measurement-protocol

I need to update revenue of existing transaction by measurement protocol.
I send request. But analitycs adds a new revenue to the existing revenue.

Expample: Original transaction have revenue: 100. Actual revenue: 150.
I send request for this transaction with revenue 150.

Result: revenue is 250, but I need 150.

Pleace, help! =)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot update the data that you already sent to Google Analytics.

If you send another transaction (event with the same transaction ID), Google will consider it as a new transaction and so the revenues will add up.

Though, it looks like there is a possibility to [reverse a transaction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en). So you may be able to update the amount in two steps.

- Reverse the original transaction
- Send the correct transaction

The original transaction will still appear, but you will also see the reversed operation and your new transaction.

In your example : 100 - 100 + 150 = 150 (original + reversed + new = new)